# Serialport works on localhost but doesn´t at deployed website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, serial-port

I´m doing a website with node js and react and I need to access to port Com of PC, I´m using serialport dependence of node js. The program shows ports ok on localhost but when I deploy to heroku or google cloud the program doesn´t show nothing.

Comment: You cannot access the client's serial port.

Comment: yes, I can´t access the client´s serial port. I can read ports on localhost but when i deploy i can´t.